# XSLT - Merging all elements and keep child elements in single parent node

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Input xml is like,

```
<figure counter="yes">
    <legend>
        <para>
            <target id="c001_f004"/>One such example is glycogen, a branched polymer of glucose molecules.</para>
    </legend>
    <legend>
        <para>
            <emph type="bold">A</emph> Monosaccharides</para>
    </legend>
    <legend>
        <para>
            <emph type="bold">B</emph> Disaccharides: sucrose</para>
    </legend>
    <legend>
        <para>
            <emph type="bold">C</emph> Oligosaccharides</para>
    </legend>
    <legend>
        <para>
            <emph type="bold">D</emph> Polysaccharides: glycogen</para>
    </legend>
    <subfigure>
        <graphic position="center" fileref="images/9781604063172_c001_f004a.jpg"/>
    </subfigure>
    <subfigure>
        <graphic position="center" fileref="images/9781604063172_c001_f004b.jpg"/>
    </subfigure>
    <subfigure>
        <graphic position="center" fileref="images/9781604063172_c001_f004c.jpg"/>
    </subfigure>
    <subfigure>
        <graphic position="center" fileref="images/9781604063172_c001_f004d.jpg"/>
    </subfigure>
</figure>
```

Output should be,

```
<figure counter="yes">
    <legend>
        <para>
            <target id="c001_f004"/>One such example is glycogen, a branched polymer of glucose molecules.</para>
        <para>
            <emph type="bold">A</emph> Monosaccharides</para>
        <para>
            <emph type="bold">B</emph> Disaccharides: sucrose</para>
        <para>
            <emph type="bold">C</emph> Oligosaccharides</para>
        <para>
            <emph type="bold">D</emph> Polysaccharides: glycogen</para>
    </legend>
    <subfigure>
        <graphic position="center" fileref="images/9781604063172_c001_f004a.jpg"/>
    </subfigure>
    <subfigure>
        <graphic position="center" fileref="images/9781604063172_c001_f004b.jpg"/>
    </subfigure>
    <subfigure>
        <graphic position="center" fileref="images/9781604063172_c001_f004c.jpg"/>
    </subfigure>
    <subfigure>
        <graphic position="center" fileref="images/9781604063172_c001_f004d.jpg"/>
    </subfigure>
</figure>
```

My XSLT is like as below,

```
<xsl:template match="legend">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="following-sibling::legend">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/> 
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

While using above XSLT, I can keep only `<para>` elements content. If I adding `<legend>` elements manually then it gives the same output like input. Could you please guide us, how to add/keep `<legend>` element single time.

Comment: Are you using XSLT 2.0 here?

Comment: Do you want to merge only sibling `legend` elements with not elements in between or would you also want to merge a `legend` for instance at the end, after the `subfigure` elements with the other `legend` elements at the beginning? Any, look into `xsl:for-each-group`, either with `group-adjacent="boolean(self::legend)"` for merging adjacent sibling elements or `group-by="node-name()"` for merging by node name.

Comment: yes..i am using XSLT 2.0..

Comment: @Sumathi Using the directions provided in the comments, if you have been able to achieve the desired output, request you to either add the solution or delete the question.